# Unhandled promise rejection on redirect in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, es6-promise

I have stumbled upon a strange issue with promises when redirecting in nodejs. In the code below I am using a function to handle writing to an object which will check if the item exists if it does it rejects, if it does not it resolves. When it resolves I am then redirecting the user to another page which contains the id used in the example in its url.

```
var Test = function() {

  var obj = {};

  function addItemToObj(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      var idAlreadyExists = obj[id] ? true : false;

      if (idAlreadyExists) {
        return reject('id already exists');
      }

      obj[id] = 'test';
      return resolve(id);
    });
  }

  return {
    createTestPage: function(request, response) {

      var id = 'testid';

      return addItemToObj(id).then(function(id) {
        return response.redirect(`/newPage/${id}`);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new Test;
```

So when I run this code I get this error:

***(node:46878) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot create property '_locals' on string 'Model already exists'***

The error is saying that I am not handling the rejection, but I am in the catch. When I remove the redirect the error goes away, but I cannot find out why.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Comment: Why do you need the function addItemToObj to checks if the key exists? 

`createTestPage: function(request, response) {

      var id = 'testid';

      if (!object.hasOwnProperty(id) {
  object[id] = "test";
  response.redirect(`/newPage/${id}`);
      } else {
  throw new Error('ID already exists');
      }
}`

Comment: You're not showing some important parts of the code that contribute to this error and that's probably where this error comes from.  Nothing we can do by only seeing this code.

Comment: The code worked for me as posted, using node.js and express,  Note if the id does exist, the test code does not respond to the browser request.